# When does the quadratic form of an operator assume non-negative values?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $H=(H,(\cdot, \cdot))$ be a Hilbert space (over $\mathbb{R}$) and $L: D(L) \subset H \longrightarrow H$, with $\overline{D(L)}=H$, a linear, self-adjoint  (not necessarily bounded). Consider the quadratic form $a: D(L) \times D(L) \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$a(u,u):=(L(u),v),\; \forall \; u,v \in D(L).$$

Suppose that $L$ admits two negatives eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \lambda_2 \in \mathbb{R}$, with eigenvectors associateds given, respectively, by $u_1,u_2 \in D(L).$

**Question.** If  $v \in D(L)$ is such that $(u_1,v)=0=(u_2,v)$, then holds
$$a(v,v) \geq 0?$$

This is true in general or under some additional hypothesis?

Comment: In finite dimensions, it holds

Comment: @Exodd Do you have some reference that? Some book?

Comment: in finite dimensions, we are talking about symmetric matrices, so you just need the Spectral Theorem

Comment: But the Spectral Theorem holds in infinite dimension and more the operator $L$ is self-adjoint which implies $L$ is simetric. What can I conclude from that?

Comment: Sadly, in infinite dimensions, you don't have all the good properties of the finite case, especially if $L$ is not bounded nor compact. But I'm not an expert, anyway

Comment: Be careful here. You say $L$ admits two negative eigenvalues.  But you don't say that these are the *only* negative eigenvalues. Is that what you intend to say?

Comment: @TedShifrin Suppose that $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are eigenvalues, not necessarily negative. Then $a(v,v)>0$ holds? Or yet, there exists $c>0$ such that $a(v,v) \geq c \|v\|^2$?

Comment: This is nonsense. Why can’t $L$ equal the negative of the identity map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to account for the fact that the spectrum is more than the eigenvalues. For instance let $H=\mathbb C\oplus\mathbb C\oplus L^2[0,1]$ and define $L$ by
$$
L(a,b,f)=(-a,-2b, -tf),
$$
where $tf$ is the function $t\longmapsto tf(t)$. Then the only eigenvalues of $L$ as $-1$ and $-2$, but $\sigma(L)=\{-2\}\cup[-1,0]$. And $L$ is negative, that is $\langle Lv,v\rangle\leq0$ for all $v$.

If you require the spectrum of $L$ to be of the form $\{\lambda_1,\lambda_2\}\cup K$ with $K\subset[0,\infty)$ then the answer is yes, by either the Spectral Theorem or Functional Calculus, that let you see that $L=\lambda_1 I\oplus\lambda_2 I\oplus T$, with $T\geq0$.

Comment: Yep. Force of habit! Thanks.